# Open link in new window with Vuetify v-btn and Vue router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuetify.js

Recent versions of Vue Router allow for links that open in a new tab, e.g. the following

```html
<router-link :to="{ name: 'fooRoute'}" target="_blank">
  Link Text
</router-link>
```

correctly renders an `<a target="_blank">`.

However, the same doesn't seem to work with a Vuetify `v-btn`, which supports router paths, for example if we want to use an icon.

```html
<v-btn icon :to="{ name: 'fooRoute'}" target="_blank">
  <v-icon>window</v-icon> Link Text
</v-btn>
```

Despite the component rendering an `<a>`, there is no `target="_blank"` attribute. How can we make this work?

Comment: Would you mind providing a [mcve] or a fiddle so we don't have to in order to see the problem and help debug. It might be a bug or an unsupported combination with vuetify `v-btn` and `:to`.

Comment: Not possible actually : https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/blob/v1.0.13/src/mixins/routable.js#L65 But you could contribute and make a PR :)

Answer (score 98):

Try the following code snippet

```html
<v-btn icon href="/fooRoute" target="_blank">
  <v-icon>window</v-icon> Link Text
</v-btn>
```

[Vuetify Button API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxXCu.png)

Answer (score 8):

To open a `new tab` or an `external link`, use the `href` attribute instead of `to`, for example:

```html
<v-btn
    href="https://letesend.com/"
    target="_blank"
    icon
>
    <v-icon>window</v-icon> Link Text
</v-btn>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround possible if you absolutely must use the ":to" binding (like in our project the links are a part of v-for with no special handling for external routes) using Vue default route which matches everything beginning with "http". Add this as the last rule after your internal routes but not after your catch-all 404 route (That matches * )

```
{
// This is a hack to use :to tag for absolute paths.
path: "/http*",
beforeEnter: to => {
  window.open(to.fullPath.substring(1), '_blank');
}
```

Then in your component, add :to tag to use the value. For example: In my project, i use the value "route" from the following object

```
 {
    title: "Help",
    detail: "Get online help and documentation.",
    icon: "mdi-help",
    color: "success darken-2",
    route: "https://www.confluence.myorg.com"
  }
```

Like so

```
<v-btn :color="l.color" text :to="l.route">
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a target to the router object worked for me:

```
<v-btn
:to="{ name: 'Edition', params: { id: item.id }, target: '_blank'}"
>

</v-btn>
```

It doesn't work with @click and $router.push, though