# Vuetify how to get a working link in a v-btn

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am a starter at vue and vuetify, explanation and examples would be very nice. I am trying to get a button that sends you to an external site. Example youtube.com .
I now have this, but it is not working.

```
    <v-btn
       color="primary"
       text
       @click="redirect(x.link)"
       >
       Share
    </v-btn>
```

This is my redirect

```
methods: {

      redirect(link) {
        window.location.href = link;
      }

    }
```

I saw some other questions using vue-router. I'm not sure how to use that.

I hope its clear what I am asking. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49654527/open-link-in-new-window-with-vuetify-v-btn-and-vue-router) , maybe can help. Regards!

Comment: `it is not working` - Is it a holiday? What do you mean its not working? Did you debug? Does the redirect function get called? Is the link variable actually not null? Did you put a [breakpoint](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints) or console.log and checked where the problem is? The code shown in the question does not have any problem per se and should work. Edit your question to Include answers to the questions I asked.

Comment: I have no clue what I did, but it works. I didn't change anything. I am dumbfounded. Thanks to the both of you!

Comment: @SilkeNL Try using the `href` or `to` prop on the `v-btn` and remove the click handler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VBtn has a `href` prop for this usage.

```
<v-btn :href="x.link">Share</v-btn>
```

`vue-router`'s purpose is to make the routing within your application (in the case of a [single page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application)).
To link to an external web site, you need an `href` attribute.

Comment: Here's the documentation: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/buttons#buttons